# What is the best data type that only accepts a few specific values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I have some values like these:

- `PHP`
- `CSS`
- `HTML`
- `JavaScript`

I want to know is that possible to define some specific values for a column as valid values? *(everything else would be invalid)*

---

I know, I can implement a tagging-system the other way. Creating a separated table which contains valid tags and checks everything for validating.

But actually that tagging-system is just as an example. All I'm trying to do is *defining some constant values for a column*.

Comment: IMO the cleanest and easiest to maintain solution is to create a seperate table with the tags and put a foreign key to it in your table.

Comment: @juergend Yeah as I said creating a separated table would be fine. But I want to know is that possible to I define some constants for a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an ENUM Type and define your constants when creating the table:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

I would only use it if it is a fixed list of some values. Like "male", "female".

Answer (score 2):

A typical way of doing this uses a foreign key relationship.

You can define a table of values like this:

```
create table skills (
    skillId int auto_increment primary key,
    skill varchar(255) unique
);

insert into table_of_values (value)
    select 'PHP' union all
    select 'CSS' union all
    . . . ;
```

Then you can validate using a foreign key.  Say:

```
create table PeopleSkills (
    PeopleSkillsId int auto_increment primary key,
    PeopleId int,
    Skill varchar(255),
    constraint fk_PeopleSkills_PeopleId foreign key (PeopleId) references People(PeopleId),
    constraint fk_PeopleSkills_Skills foreign key (Skill) references skills(skill)
);
```

Note:  This example uses strings for the foreign key reference.  I don't actually advocate that approach -- but that is the direct answer to your question.  In practice, the constraint can use the id rather than the name:

```
create table PeopleSkills (
    PeopleSkillsId int auto_increment primary key,
    PeopleId int,
    SkillId int, 
    constraint fk_PeopleSkills_PeopleId foreign key (PeopleId) references People(PeopleId),
    constraint fk_PeopleSkills_SkillId foreign key (SkillId) references Skills(skillId)
);
```